# Post back Data to the Same View using Jquery and Json data MVC2

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2, post

This is a very basic question, I think I ask very tough questions on here and they never get answered... Let me break it down to its simplest possible components and work up from there...
I have a view which requires user information to be entered in... on submit, this view calls a controller, which will give me the data that I need to put back on to this SAME view...  How do I get get that data back onto my view without calling the same view again at the end of the execution of the controller...?

Here is what I have so far (Jquery function)...

```
     $(function () {
    $("#DemoGraphSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = [];
        $.getJSON("/PatientACO.aspx/SearchByDemographic", null, function (data) {
            data = $.map(data, function (item, a) {
                return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#PatientListToAdd").html(data.join(""));
        });
    });
});
```

submit button and select list that I want populated

```
    <div >
    <select id="PatientListToAdd">Add Patient</select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my example doesn't exactly mimic your design (you might be using a page method or some questionable routing), but as long as `/PatientACO.aspx/SearchByDemographic` is returning JSON, you should be able to apply this code. Populate the `List<ListItem>` collection with your data as needed and return JSON.

I added an action called SearchByDemographic, and you will see in my jQuery further down that I use it instead of your URL. However, it still accepts POST requests and returns JSON.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SearchByDemographic()
{
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>() {
        new ListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Patient 1" },
        new ListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Patient 2" },
        new ListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Patient 3" }
    };

    return this.Json(list);
}
```

Then, my jQuery is slightly modified to use `$.ajax` which is just longhand for `$.getJSON` and it allows a few more options.

```
$('#DemoGraphSubmit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'SearchByDemographic',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, optionData) {
                var option = new Option(optionData.Text, optionData.Value);
                $('#PatientListToAdd').append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(optionData.Value).html(optionData.Text)
                );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Both good comments... Do you know why my browser keeps asking me to save the JSON data if I do not include e.preventDefault, and it does nothing when I leave it in?

Comment: @DmainEvent the `preventDefault()` function keeps the element from firing its default event e.g. an anchor will not browse to its href value, a submit button will not submit the form in which it resides, etc.

Comment: So why do we use it?  And how do I get the action to fire if I so use it?

Comment: @DmainEvent - we use it when we want to do something client side and prevent the element from performing it's default action e.g. an `<a>` element when clicked will navigate the browser to the `href` value as David says. If you're using an `<a>` element to pull data from the server via AJAX and the URL you are using is the `href` attribute value, you want to prevent the default action from happening when you click on the `<a>`. So, inside of a click event handler, you would call `preventDefault` on the event object (this is a standard w3c event normalized across browsers by jQuery) to do so.

Comment: So I guess I need to call my action method using jquery.  I thought I was doing that, but the breakpoints in my method never get called.  And the method never executes...  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DmainEvent You are potentially calling the `SearchByDemographic` action by using jQuery, but it seems odd--you request looks like you're trying to call a page method Web Forms-style and not in typical MVC fashion. Where is `SearchByDemographic` located? Is it in a controller?

Comment: Yes it most certainly is in a controller

Comment: @DmainEvent Do you have routing configured to handle your request format, because your URL isn't typical MVC-style. Can you show us your routing (global.asax) and controller (not sure of its name) code?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `GET` request along with JSON data so first thing's first, you need to allow this using 
`JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`. Let's say you have a `PatientACOController` with a `SearchByDemographic` action

```
public class PatientACOController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SearchByDemographic() 
    {  
        // code to get patients (hopefully you have something similar)
        // Patient class has Text and Value Properties
        IEnumerable<Patient> patients = PatientRepository.All()

        return Json(patients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Your jQuery code seems ok. You're sending null for data. Some small voice in the back of my head is saying that if you intend to send no data then you should use an empty object or omit it altogether. So

```
$(function () {
    $("#DemoGraphSubmit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var options = [];
        $.getJSON("/PatientACO/SearchByDemographic", function (data) {
            options = $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                          return "<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>";
                      });
            $("#PatientListToAdd").html(options.join(""));
        });
    });
});
```